How to create isolated Docker containers for each user session in a web-based code execution environment?
I am undertaking a project which is basically a clone of Repl.it. It has a feature where users can use a terminal to run their code. So, what I am doing is creating a backend server and containerizing it with Docker. I am connecting it to the client side using sockets. Now, whatever code the user is typing is automatically sent to the Docker container containing the image for the backend server, and it will run commands. Then, whatever output is generated in the logs will be sent to the user through the socket and shown in the terminal section.
Now, what I want is whenever a user opens the terminal, it should always create an isolated container for that particular user. It should not happen that a single container is being used by multiple users. Think of a scenario where one user is doing their project in React and another one is doing their project in Angular. If they are both running in the same container, the code will conflict with each other, and it will never work properly. To ensure it works properly, I want a new container to spin up from the same image—an isolated container for each and every user individually—so that their code is isolated from other users and they can freely use that terminal and run their code, just like they would be doing on their local machine with VS Code or any IDE.
I know how to host a container using ECR and ECS but don't know how to implement the above feature.
